# Pine Script - defined line to only plot from 9:30EST to 4pm EST

Tags: pine-script

i have a defined point i calculate before trading each day ("PP").  I want to plot that new line (retaining previous days), but i only want it plotted from 9:30am EST to 4pm EST.  This way it does not take up visual space during electronic trading period in Globex.

current code is as follows but it draws a line across the entire day

```
[h, l, c] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ret(), lookahead=true)
pp = (h + l + c) / 3
var line ppline = na
if pp[1] != pp      
     line.set_extend(ppline, extend.none)
ppline := line.new(bar_index, pp, bar_index, pp, width=2, extend=extend.right, color=color.blue)
if not na(ppline) and line.get_x2(ppline) != bar_index
     line.set_x2(ppline, bar_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
BarInSession(sess) => not na(time(timeframe.period, sess, "Americas/New York"))
in_session = BarInSession("930-1600")

if in_session
     // do stuff
```